# Joda-Time: How to get the day from a particular date in a year?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, jodatime

I have a list of holidays in a year. I need the following things.

1. **I need to get all the dates in a year. Then I need to remove all the
   holidays and get the remaining dates.** Something like:

   Get dates (all dates in a year)

   Get holiday dates (I already have them stored in a database)

   Get dates - holiday dates
2. Against a particular date, I need to know **what day it is** (Monday? Tuesday? What day?)

**QUESTION:-**

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, please share the simplest way of getting it done.

Comment: Have you seen (DateTime) `plusDays(int)`? You could use that to iterate every date in a year. Then there is `dayOfWeek()` for the second part. Please try this and amend your question with how far you got. :)

Comment: Have a look at their javadoc. A quick look at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html gives a lot of info.

Comment: And don't forget to check if the year is a leap year or not if iterating.

Comment: @vikingsteve OK I am just going to try it.

Comment: @vikingsteve: But plusDays(int) is of DateTime class. I just have dates, not time.

Comment: Have a look at some example code here: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ - it's perfectly alright to use `DateTime` to represent dates, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Trivial to look up this information in docs. Did not mention what was tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to first question:**

```
public static List<LocalDate> getDaysOfYear(int year, List<LocalDate> holidays) {

  LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, 1, 1);
  LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year + 1, 1, 1);
  List<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();

  while (date.isBefore(end)) {
    if (!holidays.contains(date)) {
      list.add(date);
    }
    date = date.plusDays(1);
  }

  return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

**Answer to second question:**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int dow = date.getDayOfWeek();
// dow has the values 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, ..., 7=Sunday
```

**UPDATE for question 2:**

An alternative to using numbers (or named constants like [DateTimeConstants.MONDAY](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#MONDAY) which are finally only numbers, too) is to use the property [dayOfWeek().getAsText()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/field/AbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.html#getAsText%28java.util.Locale%29). It allows access to localized names like "Monday" (English) or "Lundi" (French).

See this code example:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String nameOfWeekday = date.dayOfWeek().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

For such date-only problems the type `LocalDate` is by far the most simple and straight-forward one to use. The type `DateTime` only makes sense if you have a time part and a need for timezone calculations.

Comment: Tip… Names of day-of-week in English are provided as constants: [DateTimeConstants.MONDAY](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#MONDAY) and so on. Makes your code more readable than testing for a number 1, 2, and such.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes that is fine to use named constants, especially because JodaTime lacks of enums due to historical reasons. See also my updated answer for use of property `dayOfWeek()`.